# angularjs $http.get alter the response of a nested json array

Tags: angularjs, http, response

```
$http.get("./getData").then((response) => {/*fetch json data from server*/  
     console.log(response);/*print the response data*/  
 }
```

```
    //printed as   
    {  
        "jdata1": [{  
            "total1": 0,  
            "total2":1,  
            "othertotal1":{  
                "type":"json",  
                "value":"[{\"id\" : 123,\"ototal1\" : 2,\"ototal2\" : 3},{\"id\" : 456,\"ototal1\" : 4,\"ototal2\" : 5}]"  
            }  
        },{  
            "total1": 0,  
            "total2":1,  
            "othertotal1":{  
                "type":"json",  
                "value":"[{\"id\" : 123,\"ototal1\" : 2,\"ototal2\" : 3},{\"id\" : 456,\"ototal1\" : 4,\"ototal2\" : 5}]"  
            }  
        }  
        ],  
        "jdata2": [{  
            "test1": "1",  
            "test2": "A"  
        }, {  
            "test1": "2",  
            "test2": "B"  
        }]  
    }  
    
    //but actual data from server is   
    
    {  
        "jdata1": [{  
            "total1": 0,  
            "total2":1,  
            "othertotal1":[{  
                    "id" : 123,  
                    "ototal1" : 2,  
                    "ototal2" : 3  
                },{  
                    "id" : 456,  
                    "ototal1" : 4,  
                    "ototal2" : 5  
            }]  
            
        },{  
            "total1": 0,  
            "total2":1,  
            "othertotal1":[{  
                    "id" : 123,  
                    "ototal1" : 2,  
                    "ototal2" : 3  
                },{  
                    "id" : 456,  
                    "ototal1" : 4,  
                    "ototal2" : 5  
            }]  
        }  
        ],  
        "jdata2": [{  
            "test1": "1",  
            "test2": "A"  
        }, {  
            "test1": "2",  
            "test2": "B"  
        }]  
    }
```

Comment: why response is altered, advice on how to handle nested json array in angularjs

Comment: I am not sure if `./getData` is the correct way to access the API endpoint. This seems like you are trying to get data from a locally hosted file.

Comment: the ./getData output the json formatted data extracted from the database, but i can not understand why $http.get() response is altered to the above printed console, is there any setting to handle the above server json format ?

Comment: What happens when you try to print `"othertotal1"` by referencing it?

Comment: printing othertotal1 output in the form {  
                "type":"json",  
                "value":"[{\"id\" : 123,\"ototal1\" : 2,\"ototal2\" : 3},{\"id\" : 456,\"ototal1\" : 4,\"ototal2\" : 5}]"  
            }

Comment: but printing othertotal1 in the server side i got [{
    "id" : 123,
    "ototal1" : 2,
    "ototal2" : 3
   },{
    "id" : 456,
    "ototal1" : 4,
    "ototal2" : 5
  }]

Comment: Can you check if before returning the response there are any transformations applied on it? Server side code would be useful too.

Comment: It seems like your inner array is getting converted to a string, similar to how JSON.stringify would work on something

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/getData")
public @ResponseBody JSONObject getData {
 JSONObject jdata=dataserviceInt.getData();
 System.out.println("jdata="+jdata);//this output the above server side
 return jdata;
}

Comment: how about these client codes would the $filter alter the response  app.controller(
        "dataCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$filter', '$interval',
            function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $filter, $interval) {.....})]

Comment: Can you try using api url + `/getData`?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/test/getData return the same altered data

Comment: i got it to work, thank you for your directions